# Capture a DOS command response into a string

Tags: vb.net, string

HI I need to capture a responce ,using visual basic, of a command i send to the command prompt into a string,
I want to read from the string as soon as its captured.
The following code will work if you have a folder called  Pingfolder in the following directory "C:\" egsample C:\Pingfolder and a txt file called "ping.txt" inside of that egsample:you need this C:\Pingfolder\ping.txt
This code writes the ping responce into the ping.txt file.

```
   Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim NewProcess As New Process
        Dim StartInfoProcess As New System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo
        StartInfoProcess.FileName = "cmd"
        StartInfoProcess.RedirectStandardInput = True
        StartInfoProcess.RedirectStandardOutput = True
        StartInfoProcess.UseShellExecute = False
        StartInfoProcess.CreateNoWindow = True
        NewProcess.StartInfo = StartInfoProcess
        NewProcess.Start()
        Dim SIOSW As System.IO.StreamWriter = NewProcess.StandardInput
        SIOSW.WriteLine("cd\")
        SIOSW.WriteLine("cd Pingfolder")
        SIOSW.WriteLine("ping www.google.com > ping.txt")
        SIOSW.WriteLine("Exit")
        SIOSW.Close()
    End Sub
```

In the code above the SIOSW.WriteLine("ping www.google.com > ping.txt")
pings www.google.com and then saves the responce to ping.txt".
In the code above i want to capture the responce as a string instead of writing it to the ping.txt file. 
i need something like this:

```
dim theresault as string
theresault = SIOSW.WriteLine("ping www.google.com")
messagebox.show(theresault)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following allows me to read the responce to a string

```
     Dim thestring As String
   Dim SIOSR As System.IO.StreamReader = NewProcess.StandardOutput
    thestring = SIOSR.ReadToEnd
```

heres the code FULL code below This sends the command and saves the responce as a string then displays it as a message

```
Dim NewProcess As New Process
Dim StartInfoProcess As New System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo
Dim thestring As String
StartInfoProcess.FileName = "cmd"
StartInfoProcess.RedirectStandardInput = True
StartInfoProcess.RedirectStandardOutput = True
StartInfoProcess.UseShellExecute = False
StartInfoProcess.CreateNoWindow = True
NewProcess.StartInfo = StartInfoProcess
NewProcess.Start()
Dim SIOSW As System.IO.StreamWriter = NewProcess.StandardInput
Dim SIOSR As System.IO.StreamReader = NewProcess.StandardOutput
SIOSW.WriteLine("ping www.google.com")
Threading.Thread.Sleep(15000)
SIOSW.WriteLine("Exit")
thestring = SIOSR.ReadToEnd
    MessageBox.Show(thestring)
SIOSW.Close()
SIOSR.Close()
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to listen the the OutputDataReceived event on NewProcess.

See the documentation here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.outputdatareceived.aspx